# Using Java Messages.properties in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, properties-file

I want to use the Java Messages.properties in my Javascript. Currently I am using JSTl to spit out the messages to javascript variable like and use in my js. Is there a better approach. I looked at [jawr plugin](https://jawr.java.net/docs/messages_gen.html) Javascript i18n message generator, but didnt quite understand other than adding it servlet reference to web.xml file.

**my jsp page**

```
__messages = {
            errorPattern: '<fmt:message key="errors.match_pattern" />',
            notBothBeSet: '<fmt:message key="errors.not_both_be_set"/>'
}
```

My requirement is just to use java properties in js, wiring using JSTL sounds off. Are there any better approach ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in a Grails app, but I have it as a separate build step with Node.js.

Assuming you have the contents of a properties file in a variable `contents`, you could use something like what I have below. It could probably be more flexible on input, but it works. This assumes you don't put spaces around your `=` in your properties file. The function returns JSON, so you would want to write the return value to a JS file.

```
function getMessages(contents) {
  var splitter = /^(.*?)=(.*)$/;

  var data = contents.trim().split('\n').reduce(function(memo, line) {
    var split = line.match(splitter);

    if (split) {
      memo[split[1]] = split[2];
    }

    return memo;
  }, {});

  return JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ');
}

getMessages('test=hello\nfoo=bar');
// {
//  "test": "hello",
//  "foo": "bar"
// }
```

Comment: Finally I got the jawr plugin Javascript i18n message generator working. Its pretty neat way to read java resource bundle

**Define jawr.properties with bundle id**

`jawr.js.bundle.lib.id=/messages.js
jawr.js.bundle.lib.mappings=messages:org.myapp.java.Messages(mynamespace)[js.]`

Using mynamespace (as defined in jawr.properties) I can access all the resource bundle properties in my JSP

`window.mynamespace.property1`